# How can I get previous values record in sails afterUpdate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, orm, sails.js

Is there any way to access previous values of record in afterUpdate sails lifeCycle methods?
I need to execute event after user is updated, and send his old email as parameter. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the old value with `afterUpdate`.

Maybe you should consider using `beforeUpdate` to store the email in another table or in the session and get it back in `afterUpdate`.

Comment: but in beforeUpdate too, I gets only the updated fields, and I don't get the id, so how can I retrieve the user from the DB if I don't have his id?